# How to differentiate this negative power?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm reading the book "Calculus made easy" and I'm stuck with a step of a derivative with a negative power. Here is what is in the book:

> *Case of a negative power.*   
>   
>  Let $y=x^{-2}$. Then proceed as before $$\eqalign{y+dy&=(x+dx)^{-2}\\&=x^{-2}\left(1+\dfrac{dx}x\right)^{-2}.}$$

I don't understand what I have to do to go from 
$$
(x+dx)^{-2}
$$
to
$$
x^{-2} \cdot (1+dx/x)^{-2}
$$
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$(x+dx)^{-2} = \left[x\left(1+\frac{dx}{x}\right)\right]^{-2} = x^{-2}\left(1+\frac{dx}{x}\right)^{-2}$$